# Handling of unique_id and timestamp features for records flowing through Pub-sub to Bigquery

Tags: python-3.6, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to build a streaming/batch pipeline which read events from Pub/Sub and write them into BigQuery using python3.6

According to the documentation, Cloud Pub/Sub assigns a unique `message_id` and `timestamp` to each message, which can be used to detect duplicate messages received by the subscriber. (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq)

Requirement is as below:
1) Messages can come in any order(asynchronous messaging)
2) Unique Id and timestamp(when the record was pushed to pubsub topic / pulled from topic) should be captured to the existing record.

```
Input Data :
Name Age 
xyz  21
```

```
Output Record to bigquery:
Name  Age  Unique_Id    Record_Timestamp(time when it was written to topic or pulled from topic)

xyz   21    hdshdfd_12  2019-10-16 12:06:54
```

Can anyone provide me some link on how to handle this or inputs if we can execute this through pubsub

Answer (score 1):

You have all the wished data in the PubSub message. Be careful, the format of PubSub message [is slightly different if you use function event format](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure). The timestamp and the messageId are in the context object

[Message format](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

```
   {
     "message": {
       "attributes": {
         "key": "value"
       },
       "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
       "messageId": "136969346945",
       "publishTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
     },
     "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
   }
```

Data are base64 encoded. I recommend you to make a JSON with your data and to publish this json in PubSub. You can get a base64 string but after decoding, you have your JSON and you can use your data.

You also have the `publishedTime`, time of publication in the PubSub. You don't have the pull time. You can have it by doing a `time = Now()` in your message handler.

Now, you have all your data. You can build a BigQuery row with `<your data>,messageId,publishedTime`. You can build a file (a CSV or JSON line for example) and [perform a load job into bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data), or [use stream write](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). All depends on your requirements/preferences.